# How to find something in one sheet and add it to another?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a problem with Google Sheets. I need to create a list based on the cell contents in the new worksheet. For example: If in the 'Example1' sheet, in cell E2, the value is 'yes', add the entire row to the 'Example2' sheet. Is it possible to do it in Google Sheets?

Comment: You can write a Macro for that

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
=QUERY(Example1!A:Z; "where E='yes'"; 0)
```